# anti-CSRF tokens in HTTPS environment

Tags: tls, csrf

Does it really make sense to use anti-CSRF tokens in a web application that is accessed by HTTPS only? If yes, then what are the possible ways to attack such a web application if anti-CSRF tokens are absent?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it does make sense. HTTPS does nothing to protect you against CSRF attacks. You would carry out an CSRF attack like you would against a HTTP enabled website.

Take a look at the [CSRF description from OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29) to understand how it works. It will be obvious that the encryption of the communication channel is irrelevant for this type of attack.

Comment: Can you please explain? Linking without context is discouraged - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer